Proof that if the MRS is increasing in one good, then the other is normal
I'm self-studying Osborne and Rubinstein's Models in Microeconomic Theory and I'm having troubles understanding the following argument (p. 70), which proves the proposition that, if the demand function of a rational consumer has the property that $MRS(x_1, x_2)$ is increasing for all values of $x_2$, then $x_1$ is normal. The proof they provide is:

Fix $p_1^0$ and $p_2^0$ and let $w' > w$. Let $a$ be a solution to the consumer's problem for the budget set $B((p_1^0, p_2^0), w)$ and let $a'$ be a bundle on the frontier of $B((p_1^0, p_2^0), w')$ with $a_1' = a_1$. By the assumption on the marginal rate of substitution we have $MRS(a') > MRS(a)$, and hence the solution $b$ of the consumer's problem for the budget set $B((p_1^0, p_2^0), w')$ has $b_1 > a'_1 = a_1.$

I don't undestand how the desired conclusion follows from the fact that $MRS(a') > MRS(a)$. I asked the same question on Economics Stack Exchange and one user provided me with the following argument: since $a = (a_1, a_2)$ is optimal, we have $w = MRS(a) \cdot a_1 + a_2$ (but we do need to assume the optimal solution is not a corner one for this to go through!). Next, note that since $b$ is also optimal, we have $MRS(b) = \frac{p_1^0}{p_2^0}$ and $a_1' \neq b_1$ since $MRS(a') > MRS(a) = MRS(b)$. Now, to prove the last inference of the proof above, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $b_1 \leq a'_1$, i.e. $b_1 < a'_1$ given what we've just concluded. Then:
$$MRS(a')(a'_1 - b_1) + a'_2 - b_2 = MRS(a')(a'_1 - b_1) + w - \frac{p_1^0}{p_2^0} \cdot a'_1 - w + \frac{p_1^0}{p_2^0} \cdot b_1 = (MRS(a') - MRS(a))(a'_1 - b_1) > 0,$$
since both terms are strictly positive. So we get:
$$MRS(a') \cdot a'_1 + a'_2 > MRS(a') \cdot b_1 + b_2 > MRS(b) \cdot b_1 + b_2 = w'.$$
Now, if we could show that $a' = (a_1', a_2')$ is optimal, then we could derive the contradiction $w' > w'$ and we'd be done. The user who answered my question claimed $a'$ is optimal, but why? This is not true neither by assumption nor by construction, no?
